# Lost data in pre-processing data using Python, numpy and panda

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am operating an UCI data set 
[file URL](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data), and using Python to clean the data with "?" in the lines. The data contains 303 instance, and 6 lines contain "?". My code for cleaning the data is below:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp

def dataGen():
    infile = open('d:\\Data\\processed.cleveland.data',"r")
    outfile = open('d:\\Data\\clean.processed.cleveland.data',"w")
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if '?' not in line:
            outfile.write(line)
    dataset = np.asarray(pd.read_csv('d:\\Data\\clean.processed.cleveland.data', header=None))
return dataset
```

However, I got only 269 instances after the cleaning. I print the `dataset` and found that the last line (269th line) is:

```
268  46   1   4  140  311   0   0  120   1  1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I do not know what happens to the program. I checked output file, it shows the data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing is skipping rows that have `?` so you can just filter these out using `apply`:

```
In [11]:
import io
import pandas as pd
​
t="""56.0,1.0,2.0,130.0,221.0,0.0,2.0,163.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,7.0,0
58.0,1.0,2.0,125.0,220.0,0.0,0.0,144.0,0.0,0.4,2.0,?,7.0,0
57.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,236.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,1
38.0,1.0,3.0,138.0,175.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,?,3.0,0"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
df

Out[11]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8    9   10   11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0  0.0   1  0.0   7   0
1  58   1   2  125  220   0   0  144   0  0.4   2    ?   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0  0.0   2  1.0   3   1
3  38   1   3  138  175   0   0  173   0  0.0   1    ?   3   0

In [14]:
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x== '?', axis=1).any(axis=1)]

Out[14]:
   0   1   2    3    4   5   6    7   8   9   10   11  12  13
0  56   1   2  130  221   0   2  163   0   0   1  0.0   7   0
2  57   0   2  130  236   0   2  174   0   0   2  1.0   3   1
```

So in your case the following should work:

```
infile = pd.read_csv('d:\\Data\\processed.cleveland.data', header=None)
outfile = infile[~infile.apply(lambda x: x== '?', axis=1).any(axis=1)]
dataset = np.asarray(outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem by adding a `outfile.close()`, but your answer provide an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I should add a sentence `outfile.close()` before read the new file. Now the problem is solved.

Comment: Next time you see yourself reading and writing files try and use `with("filename", 'r') as reader:` for reading or `with("filename", 'w') as writer:` for writing. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks